# Merging Two DLL files

Tags: assembly, dll, merge

I have a DLL file (compiled - wrote in C++ and compiled using VC++) and I want to add some functions to it.
Is it possible for me to write another DLL that contain my functions and then merge my new DLL with old DLL so the result DLL contain all old and new functions?
If Yes, How can I do this?
is there any tool for that?

Comment: Why not link the executable with the 2 dll ?

Comment: You'll need to break the DLLs into object files and relink. Sadly, I am not aware of such a tool.

Comment: @mpromonet: because I don't have the executable source! both exe file and old dll are compiled files;

Comment: So you have neither the source of the executable nor of the Dll and you would like to add some functions to the Dll ? Perhaps you can consider dll injection ?

Comment: @mpromonet: I dont want add a third DLL to the app. I want every thing depend on the old DLL! so injection doesn't work for me.